# "beginner to intermediate chefs" or "beginning to intermediate chefs"?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

- This book is for *`beginner`* to intermediate chefs.
- This book is for *`beginning`* to intermediate chefs.

`Beginner` refers to a person, so it would make sense to use it with `chefs`. But including `intermediate` seems to refer to the skill level of a chef, which seems like it should be matched with `beginning` as it also describes a skill level.

Or do I need a term for `intermediate` person? Is it time to introduce the word `intermediater` to the dictionary?

Comment: I understand that the term *chef* is used as an example but I am compelled to say that a qualified chef cannot be a beginner, in the sense that you are using it, and there is no such thing as a book for beginner or intermediate chefs. An aspiring chef must either go to an academy or a culinary school, and then work in a restaurant. You want to say "cooks", as in the person who prepares meals is sometimes called a *cook*, they too can also work in a restaurant kitchen but they cannot (legally) be called a chef without professional training and qualifications.

Comment: Yes, *chef* was merely used as an example. Using *cooks* in its place wouldn't change the question. Furthermore, I question your assertion that there is a legal restriction to use of the job title of chef. Which country are you from? And do you have support for your assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intermediate` is an `adjective`, `beginner` is a `noun`, and `beginning` is either an `adjective` (she's a beginning driver...), a `noun` (in the beginning...), or a `verb` (beginning with Sally, we shall...).

I believe you are correct in choosing `beginning` over `beginner`, because `beginning` and `intermediate` can both function as adjectives. However, because `beginning chef` denotes action (the chef is beginning) as well as describes the chef's ability and `intermediate chef` only describes the chef's ability, the phrase no longer has parallel construction (and thus sounds weird to us).

My advice would be to avoid both `beginner` and `beginning`. Use a word which only describes the chef's skill level (for example, `basic`) instead.

Comment: I think your answer is good but disagree with the suggestion of using *basic* if only because, in this context, *basic* chef does not sound at all appealing...

Comment: True, the word 'basic' isn't that much of a compliment. But something akin to 'basic' should work.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with emma's answer but wanted to throw out some possible alternatives.  Part of the suggestions below is that I'm questioning if the use of "to" is making this sound worse than it is, using "and" might feel more natural and still imply anyone in between:

- This book is for beginners and intermediate chefs
- This book is for beginners and intermediate-level chefs
- This book is for beginner- to intermediate-level chefs (similar to Laura's answer but a little closer to the original )
- This book is for beginners and experienced chefs
- This book is for both new and experienced chefs

I definitely think the use of "level" can help make "intermediate sound more natural in this sentence.  Using the plural beginners may also help, as I did in the first couple examples.  Using "both" might also help it feel a bit more natural.

Comment: The use of "to" is to indicate the range (i.e. from beginning level *to* intermediate level). I see "and" is probably better, though.

Comment: The question actually doesn't have anything to do with chefs. I just used it as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the [Google Ngram viewer for the two phrases: "beginning to intermediate" and "beginner to intermediate" between 1800 and 2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beginner%20to%20intermediate%2Cbeginning%20to%20intermediate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbeginner%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbeginner%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeginner%20to%20Intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeginner%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbeginning%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbeginning%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeginning%20to%20Intermediate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeginning%20to%20intermediate%3B%2Cc0), you'll see "beginning to intermediate" has more use overall and "beginner to intermediate" has had more use in the last few years of the range.

Looking at the links in the bottom of the page we can see some sentences using the phrases:

**Beginning to intermediate:**

[2007-2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beginning%20to%20intermediate%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2007,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en):

> They include matching exercises for beginning to intermediate ESL students

[2001-2006](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beginning%20to%20intermediate%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2001,cd_max:2006&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl):

> TRANSITION FROM BEGINNING TO INTERMEDIATE ALGEBRA
>
> Intended for beginning to intermediate users of Lotus Notes
>
> Beginning to intermediate level, easily accessible; contains many problems and makes an excellent textbook

**Beginner to intermediate:**

[2006-2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beginner%20to%20intermediate%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2006,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)

> the concentration should be at the beginner to intermediate levels

[2004-2005](http://mogulmick.vbmco.com/begin.html)

> Page Title: Beginner to Intermediate

As you are referring to a book, you may want to go with beginning, since it has more use in books according to Google Ngrams. However, I tried comparing the two using Google's web search and I got [beginner to intermediate with 1,490,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beginner%20to%20intermediate%22) and [beginning to intermediate with 368,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beginning%20to%20intermediate%22). In the context of the internet I find it hard not to say that beginning to intermediate is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would write: "This book is for chefs at a beginner or intermediate level."